# keep adding up code from database

Tags: php

```
  # Check arrary not empty
    if (!empty($results)) {
    $this->code($results);

    // got the mail code from database
    // which is PG-000001
    // how do i add , like something PG-000001 ++
    }
```

this will return a result from database , my intention is to keep adding up the code that return from my database and the update back to the database.

now it was return PG-000001, how do i make it add up and be like PG-000002 and then update it and next time it will be PG-000002 and up to  000003 and so on.

how do i add up the text PG-000001?

Answer (score 1):

If all of your codes look like this, then your really shouldn’t store them that way. It appears that the `PG-` at the beginning is just a prefix. If you store the actual value as an integer, you can increment as much as you like.

Anyway, the solution to your question is that you will need to

- split the string
- increment the second part
- zero-pad the second part
- combine again

Here is a little test script:

```
$test='PG-000001';
$pattern='/(.*-)(\d+)/';
preg_match($pattern,$test,$matches);
list(,$prefix,$value)=$matches;
$value=sprintf('%06d',$value+1);
$test="$prefix$value";
print $test;
```

Translation:

- `/(.*-)(\d+)/` is the pattern that will split the string into the prefix & numeral
- `preg_match` applies the pattern and returns the result into the array `$matches`.
- `$matches` has the original string, and then the two matches
- `list()` copies elements of the array into variables. The leading comma skips the first element
- `sprintf` formats the data. In this case, the code 0-pads to 6 digits
- the double-quoted string is a simple way of recombining your data.